# Not able to go get next page data using post request in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

> I am trying to scrape data from this website.

```
import requests
pload = {
     '__EVENTARGUMENT':'Page$4'
}
r = requests.post('https://ncte.gov.in/website/RecognizedInstitutionLists.aspx?stateid=S8cOijQRRVW35%2fajiqT1hQ%3d%3d&state=KARNATAKA&regionid=4',data=pload, verify=False)

print(r.text)
```

**But above code always returns data of the first webpage. Even if I change the page number in the payload it returns the first page. How to get data on the next pages by changing the request body?**

Comment: Post request will also do work , if you can send form data accurately. Here you  will see that formdata is so much complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can get table data only using pandas too.
Here is the solution

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_html('https://ncte.gov.in/website/RecognizedInstitutionLists.aspx?stateid=S8cOijQRRVW35%2fajiqT1hQ%3d%3d&state=KARNATAKA&regionid=4')
df = dfs[0]
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   S.No.         File No.  ...           Order Type           Order
0                 1         APS05618  ...  Initial Recognition        Download
1                 2         APS02295  ...  Initial Recognition        Download
2                 3         APS02255  ...  Revised Recognition        Download
3                 4         APS03118  ...  Initial Recognition        Download
4                 5         APS05489  ...  Initial Recognition        Download
..              ...              ...  ...                  ...             ...
96              NaN              NaN  ...           Withdrawal        Download
97               86         APS01651  ...  Initial Recognition        Download
98               87  SRCAPP201630064  ...  Revised Recognition        Download
99              NaN              NaN  ...  Revised Recognition        Download
100  12345678910...   12345678910...  ...       12345678910...  12345678910...

[101 rows x 12 columns]
```